# Not able to save exported excel with dxl

Tags: ibm-doors

```
Module m = current

string s = name(m)

OleAutoObj wDocs = null

OleAutoArgs args = create()

OleAutoObj wApp = oleGetAutoObject "Excel.Application"

olePut (wApp, "visible", "true")

oleGet(wApp, "ActiveWorkBook", wDocs)

oleMethod (wDocs, "Add", args)

clear(args)

put (args, "C:\\Export\\" s) // choose a meaningful file path

oleMethod (wDocs, "SaveAs", args)


oleMethod(wApp, "Quit")
```

I exported a module but not able save with above dxl code. In the code line

```
oleMethod (wDocs, "Add", args)
```

, null parameter is returned for `wDocs`. Exported excel is not becoming active. `oleGet(wApp, "ActiveWorkBook", wDocs)` is not working.

If I save exported excel file, then I am able to change the file name with above code.
Also I able to save the blank new workbook with above code. But it is not working when file is exported from DOORS. That file is not becoming active.

Comment: Further I figured out that exported excel "Book1" is active work book. I found this by using VBA code 

`Sub Activate_Workbook()
   MsgBox (ActiveWorkbook.Name)
End Sub`

Dxl code also correct but it is not recognizing exported excel as exported excel is in some other domain may be linked to DOORS. How to bring exported excel to current domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above dxl code is correct. It is working fine in excel 2010 but not in excel 365. It is depending excel version.